# Dell Power Edge R940 RAID Failure: the foreign configuration cannot be imported since the configuration is not complete

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, dell, raid5, dell-perc

Dell Power Edge R940

RAID 5 Array

BIOS version 2.3.10

PERC H740P Adapter

Some of our guys pulled of all of our disks, one by one from the server while it`s worked, to rewrite theirs serial numbers.

Now UEFI RAID configuration utility shows that **8 of 22 disks** have **foreign** configuration, and VD state is degraded in foreign configuration import menu, while in disk group view system shows that state of this VD is "failed".

Also I have import or clear configuration menu, and when you try to merge configs, appears message:

> The foreign configuration cannot be imported since the configuration is not complete.

Is it possible to do anything with this without losing data? It`s critical, and there is no backup.

Comment: How can it be critical and have no backups? Those are contradictory ideas. Have you considered calling Dell and opening a support case wit them?

Comment: @joeqwerty Why it's have no backup another question (to be honest not for me to be asked). I`ll consider opening a case with Dell, but if here would be any help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a production server with critical data on it and you're posting your question here instead of contacting the vendor for their specific expertise and knowledge. That doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Your best course of action is to open a support ticket with Dell.

Comment: Some of your guys pulled all the disks out of a production server with no backups to perform a potentially destructive operation on them? I can only hope that you don't get fired along with them.